# Storing android facebook login data to parse

Tags: android, facebook, parsing

Can someone help me how to store facebook user profile to parse library? I make an android application. What i want is after user login with facebook, the user's information (like email, name, gender) store to parse library then the application show new activity. But, my app stuck in logging in dialog after authentication facebook login and store nothing to parse library. Can someone help me? Thankyou very much

Here is the MainActivity.java

```
    package com.contoh.mutia.persistentlogin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.parse.LogInCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public Dialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Check if there is a currently logged in user
        // and they are linked to a Facebook account.
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if ((currentUser != null) && ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(currentUser)) {
            // Go to the user info activity
            showwelkamActivity();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ParseFacebookUtils.finishAuthentication(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onLoginClick(View v) {
        MainActivity.this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                MainActivity.this, "", "Logging in...", true);
        List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");
        ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(permissions, this, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                MainActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
                if (user == null) {
                    Log.d(IsianParse.TAG,
                            "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                } else if (user.isNew()) {
                    Log.d(IsianParse.TAG,
                            "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                    showwelkamActivity();
                } else {
                    Log.d(IsianParse.TAG,
                            "User logged in through Facebook!");
                    showwelkamActivity();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void showwelkamActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, welkampage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is welkampage.java the new activity that i want to show after login facebook success

```
package com.contoh.mutia.persistentlogin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.facebook.FacebookRequestError;
import com.facebook.LoginActivity;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class welkampage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welkampage);

        // Fetch Facebook user info if the session is active
        Session session = ParseFacebookUtils.getSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            makeMeRequest();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
// Check if the user is currently logged
// and show any cached content
            showwelkamActivity();
        } else {
// If the user is not logged in, go to the
// activity showing the login view.
            startLoginActivity();
        }
    }

    private void showwelkamActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, welkampage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void makeMeRequest() {
        Request request = Request.newMeRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(),
                new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                        if (user != null) {
// Create a JSON object to hold the profile info
                            JSONObject userProfile = new JSONObject();
                            try {
// Populate the JSON object
                                userProfile.put("facebookId", user.getId());
                                userProfile.put("name", user.getName());
                                if (user.getProperty("gender") != null) {
                                    userProfile.put("gender", user.getProperty("gender"));
                                }
                                if (user.getProperty("email") != null) {
                                    userProfile.put("email", user.getProperty("email"));
                                }
// Save the user profile info in a user property
                                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                                currentUser.put("profile", userProfile);
                                currentUser.saveInBackground();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.d(IsianParse.TAG, "Error parsing returned user data. " + e);
                            }
                        } else if (response.getError() != null) {
                            if ((response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_RETRY) ||
                                    (response.getError().getCategory() == FacebookRequestError.Category.AUTHENTICATION_REOPEN_SESSION)) {
                                Log.d(IsianParse.TAG, "The facebook session was invalidated." + response.getError());
                                logout();
                            } else {
                                Log.d(IsianParse.TAG,
                                        "Some other error: " + response.getError());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        request.executeAsync();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_welkampage, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void onLogoutClick(View v) {
        logout();
    }

    private void logout() {
        // Log the user out
        ParseUser.logOut();

        // Go to the login view
        startLoginActivity();
    }

    private void startLoginActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here is Isianparse.java

```
package com.contoh.mutia.persistentlogin;

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;

public class IsianParse extends Application {
    static final String TAG = "MyApp";
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this,"appid","mykey");
}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm in the same boat , I am novice who is using parse and this works for me.

```
//Make sure that a session is opened and that you asked for the required permission

if(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession().isOpened())
{

Request.newMeRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback()
{
@Override
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response)
{
if (user != null)
{
 String Name = user.getName;
 String email = user.getEmail; 
//Use the get Method to get the info from facebook

//Then save it to the parse DB
 ParseObject post = new ParseObject("post");    
    post.put("name", Name); 
        post.saveInBackground();                         
}
  }
  }).executeAsync();
  }
```

Comment: By the way , Never post your parse keys in the question.

Comment: @Shumimura are you getting stuck in logging in or in getting the details and storing it in the parse DB?

Comment: Also place your a copy of onActivityResult in welkampage.java @shumimura

Answer (score 0):

My LoginFragment looks like this, and stores the user's Facebook name to shared preferences. I used https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.1 to implement login and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/ to obtain data from the logged-in user.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.facebook.*;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "LoginFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    return view;
}

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {

        final SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                "fbInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (session != null && session.getState().isOpened()) {
            Log.i("sessionToken", session.getAccessToken());
            Log.i("sessionTokenDueDate", session.getExpirationDate().toLocaleString());
        }
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("access_token", session.getAccessToken());
        new Request(session, "/me", params, HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                .getGraphObject()
                                .getInnerJSONObject();
                        try {
                            prefs.edit().putString("name", graphResponse.getString("name")).commit();
                            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Welcome " + graphResponse.getString("name"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();

        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                    try {
                        String userId = user.getId();
                        prefs.edit().putString("id", userId).commit();
                        prefs.edit().putString("profile_url", "https://graph.facebook.com/"
                                + user.getId() + "/picture?type=large").commit();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).executeAsync();

        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MainPage.class);
        startActivity(i);
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
    }
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // For scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered. Trigger it if it's open/closed.
                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null &&
                (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode,
            resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but what i want is the apps store user's Facebook name to parse.com. do you know how to do that?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize you meant using the Parse library, thought you just meant parsing the JSON response. Sorry, don't have any experience with parse